# Как отследить прикосновения обьектов к друг другу?

Tags: android

Меня мучает очень интересный вопрос, а именно: как отследить прикосновения обьектов к друг другу? Допустим игрок столкнулся с врагом и умер. Как сделать?
Напишите код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ваш вопрос имеет множество ответов, зависящих от уже имеющегося кода! Невозможно дать ответ, Вы даже язык программирования еще не указали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса совершенно неясно, как написать код.
Однако есть простой принцип: все объекты в игре представляются как окружности определённого радиуса с центрами (x ; y).

Каждый цикл работы программы вы можете делать подобную проверку: если расстояние между объектами меньше либо равно сумме их радиусов, то объекты столкнулись/соприкоснулись

Расстояние ищется по теореме Пифагора.